# Chrome video buffering stops at roughly 40%

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I am using videojs (although irrelevant I believe, I include this fact anyway) to server html5 video.

The problem is, in chrome, buffering stops just after 2.84MB have been downloaded of the video (this seems variable, I just took the [figure from here](http://oddlystudios.com/blog/html5-video-problems-in-chrome/)). This represents between 40-60% of my video files.

I realise I'm probably not going to get over this problem from a webpage perspective, my question is:

**What can I do to make the video buffer 100% in Google Chrome?**

It is *vital* that my video be buffered 100% before I can do anything else with it, the reason for this being that I immediately need to be able to seek to several places in the video very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have added the video an the page to the AppCache.  This will ensure that the entire video is downloaded and stored locally.  However, the Browser still might only buffer the same percentage in the video element but because it is stored locally on the disk then Random access is very quick.

Alternatively if you are concerned by the buffering you could XHR the video in and store it in  either IndexedDB or the FileSystem APi.

Comment: This would be a good option but some browsers limit their appcache to 5MB (namely: Chrome!!) which doesn't solve my problem. I can't do it with XHR either because it wouldn't be fast enough. I believe indexedDB isn't widely used enough and neither is the FileSystem API...